# Can the telebot's method `get_chat()` be usefull for private channels/groups?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, telebot

I know how to introduce a chat in the bot with the method `telebot.get_chat(CHAT_ID)` but how can i do when it's a private channel or a private group? how can i get his id or his information? the only thing that i have is the link and the method don't allow that.

By the way, i am using Python

I want to work with the method `telebot.get_chat()` and `telebot.get_chat_member()` with private groups and private channels